# Disable text input change but take it with its value in jQuery

Tags: jquery, database, input, disabled-input, jquery-attributes

I am filling textbox elements with some data come from database. I am using the same form for different roles. Some roles can update these values but others cannot. So, I want to disable them for edit.

I both used:

```
$("input:eq(1)").attr("disabled", true);
```

and

```
$("input:eq(2)").prop('disabled', true);
```

It works seemingly but when I try to update the form, these values are stored null in database. At first it fetches and fills the textboxes disabled, but when I click update button, the values are sent to DB as null. How can I avoid that problem and provide a solution to push unchanged (because you cannot change) input values into DB?

Comment: `disabled` inputs still have values, how are you re-grabbing the values to send back to the DB... `("input:eq(2)").val()` still returns a value even if it's disabled.

Comment: actually I am working on a written project and I could not the function which stores data to DB. It creates custom forms dynamically in PHP and there are thousands of code I am looking for the method but I could not find. Input elements are generated dynamically and have no id or class as I see. I interfere to only html-jquery layer. Sorry for my deficiency.

Comment: But readonly attribute worked...

Comment: @JoshuaJeanThree disabled cannot pass value to DB.You may take these values by hidden input field(s).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue with disabled inputs is that they don't get passed to the database on a `submit` post. Try changing them to this:

```
$("input:eq(1)").attr("readonly", true);
```